# TFS project not deploying to azure

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012, tfs

Up to about a week ago when I checked in any changes to my source into TFS, I would queue a build in Visual Studio 2012 and the solution would get delivered to my Azure as a Web App.

Yesterday, I noticed that it stopped delivering.  I have tried to resolve by  disconnecting from Visual Studio Online and reconnect, without success.  I have also tried by creating a new Web App & connecting to my project in VisualStudio.com without success.

Can someone direct me to the "Magic"?  I want to know how I would find out if my project on visualstudio.com is broken or is it something in Azure.  How does Azure get notified from VisusalStudio.com-TFS that a build is ready to be published?  Or does Azure "constantly" check?

Thanks

Comment: You should have a continuous delivery CI build. Go look at the build and see if it's failing.

Comment: The build is not failing.  All "Green" check mark.

Comment: Look at the build details. The build is responsible for pushing the binaries to Azure.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, The summary and the log file shows that it built items.  A few warnings occured  "error(s), 8 warning(s)" though.

Comment: Create Workspace

01:39
Get Workspace

00:01
Create Label

00:42
Compile, Test, and Associate Changesets and Work Items

00:42
Compile and Test

00:42
Run MSBuild for Project     Get Impacted Tests, Index Sources and Publish Symbols

00:00
Get Impacted Tests

00:14
Index Sources

00:41
Drop Files to Drop Location

Comment: I do notice that the "graph" has 1 Red bar and 8 Green bars.   Though I see nothing that errored out.  Does the red bar represent something failing?